# Unable to hit api with other pc on the same network for a multi tenancy application in django

Tags: django, networking, django-rest-framework, multi-tenant

I have successfully applied multi tenancy architecture with same database and separate schema for each tenant using Django and postgresql. But while trying to access the api's with a computer on the same network using the ip address I am getting `404 Not found`. While on the main computer I am able to hit the api using `localhost` when the tenant domain is `tenant1.localhost` and to allow other computers on the same network I tried changing tenant domain to `<my_ip>.tenant1` but it is not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you serving your app? Config settings and descriptions of your setup will also help others narrow down the issue.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.